# How to upload table/data frame from R to BigQuery?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, dplyr, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I feel like this method has changed up multiple times over the years and I haven't been able to keep up with the change.

Quite simply, how can I upload a regular data frame/table from R to BigQuery:

**Here was my original approach and error**

```
job = insert_upload_job(
                        project = "projectid", 
                        dataset = "dataset",
                        table =  "tablename", 
                        values = table_wanting_to_upload,
                        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE', 
                        create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED") # pushing table to BQ
```

**And this is my error**

```
Error: billing is not a string (a length one character vector).
In addition: Warning message:
'insert_upload_job' is deprecated.
Use 'bq_perform_upload' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("bigrquery-deprecated").
```

**Naturally, I use R's suggestion and use `bq_perform_upload` instead**

```
job = bq_perform_upload(
                        project = "projectid", 
                        dataset = "dataset",
                        table =  "table_name", 
                        values = table_wanting_to_upload,
                        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE', 
                        create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED") # pushing table to BQ
```

**And I get the following error:**

```
**Error in as_bq_table(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default**
```

**I don't understand what "x" means and the documentation around the `bq_perform_upload` function is lacking. I then tried to do the following to satisfy the **x error****

```
job = bq_perform_upload(x = predictions, 
                        project = "projectid", 
                        dataset = "dataset",
                        table =  "table_name", 
                        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE', 
                        create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED") # pushing table to BQ
```

**And I then get the following error which is unclear to what the issue is**

```
Error in UseMethod("as_bq_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_bq_table' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data. Frame')"
```

**The method used to be much simpler, for example & simply:**

```
job <- bq_perform_upload("project","dataset","table_name", dataframe)
```

**Answer**

```
bqr_upload_data(projectId = 'project',
                datasetId = 'dataset', tableId = 'table_name', upload_data = predictions ,
                create = c("CREATE_IF_NEEDED"),
                schema = NULL, sourceFormat = c("CSV", "DATASTORE_BACKUP",
                                                "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON", "AVRO"), wait = TRUE, autodetect = TRUE,
                nullMarker = NULL, maxBadRecords = NULL, allowJaggedRows = FALSE,
                allowQuotedNewlines = FALSE, fieldDelimiter = ",")
```

Comment: Figured it out using `bigQueryR` answer is now in the question

Comment: btw, the one thing that was clear in ```bq_perform_upload``` document was the requirement for ```x```, because it does list it as a required field given it is in the command with no default specified if you don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using the `bigQueryR` (which I read is no longer maintained) and just use the `bigrquery` package.

So, in relation to your error, `x` is something that can be coerced to a `bq_table` object, which it seems is a reference to a table in BigQuery, as opposed to an object that *is* a table in itself. The simplest way to create an object that is coercible to a `bq_table` object is just a string with the reference to the table, `"project.dataset.table_name"`, the same as in a `FROM` statement in SQL. Conversely, when you were pointing it to the dataframe you want to upload, it doesn't know how to coerce that into a table reference (`bq_table`) for BigQuery.

So, I'm assuming you already have a pre-existing project and dataset in BiqQuery, given you're specifying those.

From there it's as simple as this:

```
bq_table_upload("project.dataset.table_name", predictions)
```

If the table doesn't yet exist in BigQuery it will try to create it for you, but I found that it doesn't do this in a sensible way (replicating the table schema from the data frame) and instead seems to base the column data types on a sample of the data within the dataframe (e.g. even for a CHARACTER variable in a dataframe, if the sample it scans appears to be and INT64, it will create it as an INT64, then fail when it hits an alpha character).

So you can first create a table to replicate the data frame schema if it doesn't already exist.

```
bq_table_create("project.dataset.table_name", as_bq_fields(predictions))
```

`as_bq_fields()` is a handy way of coercing the structure of the dataframe into a `bq_fields` object to define the columns.

And, the other piece I didn't know yet (having never used BigQuery before) was that you need to have a project, and then a dataset (analogous to schema or database in other DBMS), so I first had to create my dataset.

```
bq_dataset_create("project.dataset")
```

Now, why it took me (and I assume alse you) an hour or two to figure this out, and seems to have stumped so many people, I don't understand. It seems something that should be clearly documented and easy to understand. But hey...

Worth noting is the `bigrquery` functions are named `bq_noun_action`, which helped me to figure things out (`bq_perform_upload` seems to break from this convention).